# How to get the project source folder in Lazarus? (ComponentEditor)

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus

I understand that a compiled software has no access to the sources. However, this question is intended for the ComponentEditor.

Creating a custom component under LCL & Linux, I am creating now the editor, which would need access to the sources folder of the project to generate/manage metadata files and add them to the resources (*.rc).

Under Embarcadero-Delphi, I can do this with `GetActiveProject.fileName` from `ToolsAPI` unit.

**What is the cross-platform LCL equivalent to `GetActiveProject.fileName` to get the project source directory in a custom component editor?**

Example in Delphi:

```
ProjectDir := ExtractFilePath( GetActiveProject.fileName );
```

Comment: Does Lazarus even expose an equivalent of Delphi's ToolsAPI? I've never heard of that being a thing. But then, I don't code for Lazarus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained at [https://www.freepascal.org/~michael/articles/lazide1/lazide1.pdf](https://www.freepascal.org/%7Emichael/articles/lazide1/lazide1.pdf) the equivalent of **Open Tools API** are **Lazarus IDE interface**.

Here [https://www.freepascal.org/~michael/articles/lazide2/lazide2.pdf](https://www.freepascal.org/%7Emichael/articles/lazide2/lazide2.pdf) more information about them...

Comment: `LazarusIDE.ActiveProject.ProjectInfoFile` from unit `LazIDEIntf` 
I put the answer here, as links tend to break.